# Could Reese know he was John's father?

Tags: terminator-series, the-terminator

I wonder if Reese could know, or at least strongly suspect he was John's father.

By a quick calculation, after making love with Sarah, and if he knows John's age, he probably died being aware of this truth.

It might be pure speculation or maybe I missed subtle hints in the movie. But is there canon source that could confirm this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

He may very well have *suspected* this truth, but couldn't have known for sure.  Unless maybe John told him so before he went back in time, of course.  I don't remember if there's any canon one way or another on that particular point, and I haven't been keeping up with the more recent movies in the franchise.

The events of the first Terminator movie take place over the course of a few days, at most.  Sarah herself didn't even know she was pregnant until it was all over.  For all Reese knew, Sarah could already have been pregnant before he arrived (and not yet aware of it), or she could have become pregnant by another man later (after his death, once he knew *that* was coming.)  So, even knowing John's age in the future is not conclusive proof that he was the father.

Even knowing John's *exact birth date* wouldn't be enough to deduce this information conclusively, since the human gestation cycle is not 100% predictable and every woman's pregnancy is unique.  A baby is considered to be "full term" (ie: not premature) if it is born after 37 weeks, but it could be as many as 40 - 42 weeks before medical professionals decide to induce labour artificially (depending on a variety of factors.)  There's basically a whole month of potential wiggle room there.